# Fast conversion of C/C++ vector to Numpy array

Tags: c++, python, arrays, numpy, swig

I'm using SWIG to glue together some C++ code to Python (2.6), and part of that glue includes a piece of code that converts large fields of data (millions of values) from the C++ side to a Numpy array. The best method I can come up with implements an iterator for the class and then provides a Python method:

```
def __array__(self, dtype=float):
    return np.fromiter(self, dtype, self.size())
```

The problem is that each iterator `next` call is very costly, since it has to go through about three or four SWIG wrappers. It takes far too long. I can guarantee that the C++ data are stored contiguously (since they live in a std::vector), and it just feels like Numpy should be able to take a pointer to the beginning of that data alongside the number of values it contains, and read it directly.

Is there a way to pass a pointer to `internal_data_[0]` and the value `internal_data_.size()` to numpy so that it can directly access or copy the data without all the Python overhead?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So it looks like the only real solution is to base something off `pybuffer.i` that can copy from C++ into an existing buffer. If you add this to a SWIG include file:

```
%insert("python") %{
import numpy as np
%}

/*! Templated function to copy contents of a container to an allocated memory
 * buffer
 */
%inline %{
//==== ADDED BY numpy.i
#include <algorithm>

template < typename Container_T >
void copy_to_buffer(
        const Container_T& field,
        typename Container_T::value_type* buffer,
        typename Container_T::size_type length
        )
{
//    ValidateUserInput( length == field.size(),
//            "Destination buffer is the wrong size" );
    // put your own assertion here or BAD THINGS CAN HAPPEN

    if (length == field.size()) {
        std::copy( field.begin(), field.end(), buffer );
    }
}
//====

%}

%define TYPEMAP_COPY_TO_BUFFER(CLASS...)
%typemap(in) (CLASS::value_type* buffer, CLASS::size_type length)
(int res = 0, Py_ssize_t size_ = 0, void *buffer_ = 0) {

    res = PyObject_AsWriteBuffer($input, &buffer_, &size_);
    if ( res < 0 ) {
        PyErr_Clear();
        %argument_fail(res, "(CLASS::value_type*, CLASS::size_type length)",
                $symname, $argnum);
    }
    $1 = ($1_ltype) buffer_;
    $2 = ($2_ltype) (size_/sizeof($*1_type));
}
%enddef


%define ADD_NUMPY_ARRAY_INTERFACE(PYVALUE, PYCLASS, CLASS...)

TYPEMAP_COPY_TO_BUFFER(CLASS)

%template(_copy_to_buffer_ ## PYCLASS) copy_to_buffer< CLASS >;

%extend CLASS {
%insert("python") %{
def __array__(self):
    """Enable access to this data as a numpy array"""
    a = np.ndarray( shape=( len(self), ), dtype=PYVALUE )
    _copy_to_buffer_ ## PYCLASS(self, a)
    return a
%}
}

%enddef
```

then you can make a container "Numpy"-able with

```
%template(DumbVectorFloat) DumbVector<double>;
ADD_NUMPY_ARRAY_INTERFACE(float, DumbVectorFloat, DumbVector<double>);
```

Then in Python, just do:

```
# dvf is an instance of DumbVectorFloat
import numpy as np
my_numpy_array = np.asarray( dvf )
```

This has only the overhead of a single Python <--> C++ translation call, not the N that would result from a typical length-N array.

A slightly more complete version of this code is part of my [PyTRT project at github](https://github.com/sethrj/PyTRT/blob/master/tools/SWIG/numpy.i).

Answer (score 2):

You will want to define [`__array_interface__()` instead](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.interface.html?highlight=__array_interface__#__array_interface__). This will let you pass back the pointer and the shape information directly.

Comment: can you provide a little more detail for a practical implementation? Is there also a way to do it without having to compile my project against the Numpy header files? Thanks.

Comment: it also says that's a legacy interface.

Comment: `__array_interface__` is just a plain dict with plain types inside of it. No need to compile with any Numpy headers. Ignore the note that calls it "legacy". I thought I had deleted that already. If you like, you can implement the PEP 3118 buffer interface, but this is easier.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe it would be possible to use f2py instead of swig. Despite its name, it is capable of interfacing python with C as well as Fortran. See http://www.scipy.org/Cookbook/f2py_and_NumPy

The advantage is that it handles the conversion to numpy arrays automatically.

Two caveats: if you don't already know Fortran, you may find f2py a bit strange; and I don't know how well it works with C++.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I do know some FORTRAN, but I'm using a lot of `C++`-y features in my code: templates, typedefs, etc. I'd also rather not introduce another dependency.

Comment: Fair enough re C++. You would probably have to write intermediate plain C wrappers, which could be a pain. On the other hand, it is not really another dependency since f2py is part of numpy, which you are already using. You would not need a fortran compiler.

Answer (score 0):

If you wrap your vector in an object that implements Pythons [Buffer Interface](http://docs.python.org/c-api/buffer.html), you can pass that to the numpy array for initialization (see [docs](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.html), third argument). I would bet that this initialization is *much* faster, since it can just use `memcpy` to copy the data.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. Do you have any examples of using the `pybuffer_mutable_binary` or other interface in SWIG to implement the `__buffer__` interface for, e.g., floats?

Comment: @Seth: Sorry, I cannot help you there.

Comment: So it looks like I would have to implement the entire buffer interface for this class by hand from scratch. SWIG only provides the capability of *reading other buffers*, not exporting buffer functions.