# How to get my own C++ array class to work with numpy using SWIG and g

Tags: python, c++, numpy, swig

I created my own 2D array class in C++ and got it to work with Python using [SWIG](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SWIG). I also extended it to have some basic functionality like NumPy arrays. For example, I created a method in my Array2D class, **getitem**, which returns the elements of the array:

```
%extend Array2D{
    double __getitem__(vector<int> v) {
        return (*self)[v[0]][v[1]];
    }
}
```

After compiling the C++ extension using SWIG, I can import this into Python and get an Array2D object:

```
>>> import myclass
>>> A = myclass.Array2D(2,2,1.0)
```

which creates a 2x2 matrix of ones. Because of my extension method, I can retrieve individual elements just like with NumPy.

```
>>> A[0,1]
>>> 1.0
```

This is great and all, but when I try to use NumPy's `mean` function, I get the following error:

```
>>> mean(A)
>>> TypeError: in method 'dblArray2D___getitem__', argument 2 of type 'std::vector< int >'
```

It seems that NumPy's `mean` function doesn't know what to do with std::vector. What do I need to do with my **getitem** method or SWIG interface file to get my Array2D to use NumPy's mean function?

Comment: First of all I would suggest to pass `v` by reference, or even constant reference

Comment: related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18211783/make-a-c-class-look-like-a-numpy-array-using-swig

Answer (score 1):

My guess is that you have to provide an overload of the C++ `__getitem__` in your `%extend` that accepts one int, because `mean` flattens the array so it probably calls `array[i]` i.e. with one index, not two.

Comment: I think you're right. I had to get array[i] to return the row vector. Then it all worked!